react-form-hook - no errors for array schema
I have the following schema:
const lectureOption = z
  .object({
    duration: z.number(),
    price: z.string(),
    enabled: z.boolean(),
  })
  .refine(
    (value) => {
      if (value.enabled) {
        return price.safeParse(value.price).success;
      }
      return true;
    },
    { message: 'Cena nie może być niższa niż 2 PLN.' }
  );

export const arrayOfLectureOptions = z.array(lectureOption);

And I use it like this:
interface Props {
  form: UseFormReturn<SaveLectureSchemaType>;
}

export const OptionsStep = ({ form }: Props) => {
  const {
    register,
    formState: { errors, isValid },
    control,
    watch,
  } = form;

  const { fields: optionFields } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: 'options',
  });

  console.log('Errors', errors, isValid, 'Array', optionFields);

  watch();

  return (
    <FormWrapper
      title='Cena'
      description='Ustal cenę za poszczególną długość zajęć.'
    >
      <div className='grid grid-cols-3 gap-4'>
        {optionFields.map((field, i) => (
          <div key={field.id} className='flex flex-col gap-2'>
            <div className='flex items-center justify-between'>
              <Label
                htmlFor={`options.${i}.price`}
              >{`Cena za ${field.duration} minut`}</Label>
              <FormSwitch
                control={control}
                errors={errors}
                name={`options.${i}.enabled`}
              />
            </div>
            <FormCurrencyInput
              key={i}
              name={`options.${i}.price`}
              errors={errors}
              control={control}
              disabled={!watch(`options.${i}.enabled`)}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </FormWrapper>
  );
};

Unfortunately, it does not work in the sense that errors array does not contains errors for options even though the price attribute in one of the item is invalid and hence should raise error. What am I doing wrong? I need to raise an error if some item is enabled and the price is invalid. What can I do? Is my schema fine? formState.isValid properly show false but there are no errors even though I set mode: "all".
